# How do I split up this object and insert its elements into the list as individual objects? R

Tags: r

I have the following list. As you can see the 5th element contains multiple variables. I want to split the 5th element up and insert each single variable into the overall list as an individual element.

```
[[1]]
[1] "319"

[[2]]
[1] "321"

[[3]]
[1] "328"

[[4]]
[1] "333"

[[5]]
[1] "344"  " 345" " 346"

[[6]]
[1] "353"
```

I'm coding in R Studio. I want it to do this -->

```
[[1]]
[1] "319"

[[2]]
[1] "321"

[[3]]
[1] "328"

[[4]]
[1] "333"

[[5]]
[1] "344"   

[[6]]
[1] "345"

[[7]]
[1] "346"

[[8]]
[1] "353"
```

Comment: `do.call(c,list)` will convert it to a vector. Call `as.list` afterward if you really want it as a list.

Comment: @BrianDavis Thank you so much!! It worked!!